# conditionally show options in angular dropdown is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown

I am trying to implement dropdown in Angular, in that I need to show dropdown's option conditionally for example if it satisfies the first condition means the option should have 'A', 'B', 'C and 'D' else means the options should have 'A', 'C' and 'D', this is what I am trying,

dropdown.component.html

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="Abc" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-info">Abc:</label>
  <div class="mx-sm-2 text-center">
      <select class="form-control-sm" formControlName="Abc" [(ngModel)]="abc"
            id="dropdown" (change)='setOptions()'>
          <option *ngFor="let wm of Options" [value]="wm"> {{wm}} </option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

dropdown.component.ts

```js
public Options = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

setOptions() {
  if (this.mode == 'ac') {
    this.Options = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
  } else if (this.mode == 'aA') {
    this.Options = ['A', 'C', 'D']
  } else if (this.mode == 'n') {
    this.Options = ['A', 'C', 'D']
  }
}
```

I am getting this.mode value from server side , this is the condition for showing dropdown's option, however it is not showing the option based on the given condition.
It showing options as 'A', 'B', 'C' and 'D'

Comment: Do you call `setOptions()` after you get the server response?

Comment: yes, I am calling setOptions() after get the data  from server

Comment: **Never** use formControlName and [(ngModel)] in the same tag. NOTE: use a simple *ngIf to not show the option "B". In html you can use `myform.get('Abc')?.value` to know the value of a FormControl that belong to the form

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `this.mode` every time you change selection

```
  public Options= ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

  setOptions() {
    this.mode = this.""NAME_OF_YOUR_FORM_GROUP"".get('abc').value;
    if (this.mode == 'ac') {
      this.Options= ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    } else if (this.mode == 'aA') {
      this.Options= ['A', 'C', 'D']
    } else if (this.mode == 'n') {
      this.Options= ['A', 'C', 'D']
    }
  }
```